# Проблема с запуском приложения на Heroku Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis

Пытаюсь запустить приложение на Heroku и выдает такую ошибку. IP к редису порописан `unix://localhost:6379`, но он все еще просит написать его по одному из трех шаблонов, перечисленных в самом низу. Пробовал все три варианта.

[image: запус]

Так же мой `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --preload
```

И ссылка на редис в основном приложении `app`:

```
redis = from_url(os.environ.get('unix://localhost:6379'))
```

UPD:

```
from_url(os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/'))
```

Comment: Вы проверяли, что у вас возвращает сам `os.environ.get('unix://localhost:6379')`?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно у вас нет переменной среды `unix://localhost:6379`, попробуйте просто:

```
redis = from_url('unix://localhost:6379')
```